Hankel transform of $f(r)=\frac{\mathrm{erf}(a+r/b)-\mathrm{erf}(a-r/b)}{r}$
I enconter a Hankel transform dealing with the Ewald method.
the Hankel transform of zero order is defined as
$$F(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(r)J_{0}(kr)rdr,$$
where $J_{0}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of zero order.
in my case,
$$f(r)=\frac{\mathrm{erf}(a+r/b)-\mathrm{erf}(a-r/b)}{r},$$
where $a$ and $b$ are two positive constant and $\mathrm{erf}$ is the error fucntion.
Could someone help? thank you!

I see $$rf(r) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{a-r/b}^{a+r/b} e^{-s^2} \ \text ds$$ Maybe you can do something with that? Change order of integration maybe.

Is $a$ small ? Because this is the one making the problem.

Unfortunately, $a$ is not always small, in some cases it is big.

@AlexJones thanks for answering, could you elaborate more on how to change the order of integration?

The problem being with $a$, we could try a series solution
$$\text{erf}\left(a+\frac{r}{b}\right)-\text{erf}\left(a-\frac{r}{b}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\, a^{2n}$$ where
$$\alpha_{n+2}=-\frac{ 2\,\alpha_{n+1}} {b\,(n+2) }\,r-\frac{2\, n\,\alpha_n }{(n+1) (n+2)}$$
with
$$\alpha_{0}=\text{erf}\left(\frac{r}{b}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad \alpha_{1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\,e^{-\frac{r^2}{b^2}}$$ The integrals can be computed recursively
This would lead to
$$\frac 2 k \text{erfc}\left(\frac{b k}{2}\right)-\frac{2 b }{\sqrt{\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{4} b^2 k^2}\,a^2+\frac{b
   \left(b^2 k^2+2\right)}{6 \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{4} b^2 k^2}\,a^4-$$ $$\frac{b \left(b^4 k^4+4 b^2k^2+12\right)}{180 \sqrt{\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{4} b^2 k^2}\,a^6+\frac{b \left(b^6 k^6+6 b^4 k^4+36 b^2k^2+120\right)}{10080 \sqrt{\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{4} b^2 k^2}\,a^8-$$ $$\frac{b \left(b^8 k^8+8 b^6 k^6+72 b^4
   k^4+480 b^2 k^2+1680\right)}{907200\sqrt{\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{4} b^2 k^2}\,a^{10}+\cdots$$

thank you for answering! I am wondering if this series has a more compact form that is related to the Bessel function. Moreover, I am also a little bit worried about the convergence of this series since $a$ may not be small.

@WzS. The problem is with $a$.  $$I_n=\int_0^{\infty } r^{2 n}
\left(\text{erf}\left(a+\frac{r}{b}\right)-\text{erf}\left(a-\frac{r}{b} \right)\right) , dr$$ does not converge for any $n$

This is not an answer really, only a solution  generated from
$\tt Mathematica$:
$$
\int_0^{\infty } J_0(k x) \left(\text{erf}\left(a+\frac{x}{b}\right)-\text{erf}\left(a-\frac{x}{b}\right)\right) \,
   dx=\\\text{HankelTransform}\left[\frac{\text{erf}\left(a+\frac{x}{b}\right)-\text{erf}\left(a-\frac{x}{b}\right)}{x},x,k\right]=\\\frac{2}{k}-\frac{(2 b) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(a^2\right)^n
   \left(-\frac{1}{4} \left(k^2 b^2\right)\right)^m \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m}{m! n! \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{m-n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
Double infinte series is not expressible even for Kampé de Fériet function or Horn function
$\tt Mathematica$ code:
F1[a_, b_, k_] := NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, k  x]  (Erf[a + x/b] - 
Erf[a - x/b]), {x, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
F2[a_, b_, k_, M_] := N[2/k - (2*b)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]*
Sum[( ((a^2)^n)  ((-((k^2*b^2)/4))^m)  Pochhammer[1/2, m] )/(
m! n! Pochhammer[3/2, m - n] Pochhammer[1/2, n]), {n, 0, M},{m, 0, M}], 20];
F3[a_, b_, k_] := HankelTransform[ (Erf[a + x/b] - Erf[a - x/b])/x, x, N@k]; 
{F1[5, 1, 1], F2[5, 1, 1, 100], F3[5, 1, 1]}

(*{0.425151623946900909, 0.42515162394690068250, 0.425152}*)

